# Wait for stdout on Popen

Tags: python, python-3.x, testing, flask, python-3.6

I am trying to setting up an acceptance test harness for a flask app and I am currently struggling to wait for the app to start before making calls.

Following construct works fine:

```
class SpinUpTests(unittest.TestCase):
def tearDown(self):
    super().tearDown()
    self.stubby_server.kill()
    self.stubby_server.communicate()

def test_given_not_yet_running_when_created_without_config_then_started_on_default_port(self):
    self.not_yet_running(5000)

    self.stubby_server = subprocess.Popen(['python', '../../app/StubbyServer.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    time.sleep(1)#<--- I would like to get rid of this

    self.then_started_on_port(5000)
```

I would like to wait on stdout for:

self.stubby_server = subprocess.Popen(['python', '../../app/StubbyServer.py'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(1)#<--- I would like to get rid of this

> - Running on http://127.0.0.1:[port]/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)

I tried

```
for line in self.stubby_server.stdout.readline()
```

but `readline()` never finishes, tho I already see the output in the test output window.

Any ideas how I can wait for the flask app to start without having to use an explicit `sleep()`?

Comment: Ah, yes. I ran through this exact problem. My solution was to actually make use of [retry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry) and I would *try* my call again until it worked within the retry timeout I set. Ultimately I kept retrying based on the exception that was raised. This solved my problem.

Comment: Here you go. I actually have it on GitHub. This should do the trick: https://github.com/internap/fake-ubersmith/blob/e7f53cf0fcf2448f7b0632b454a17faed369bc2c/tests/integration/base.py#L48

Comment: Use .read(1) to read a character and then concat it with the string before. If a special character is readed yield the string in a generator and then reset your string.

Comment: @cmdLP unfortunately `read(1)` also returns nothing :(

Comment: Maybe instead of time.sleep join expressioms with "and" keyword. self.stubby_server = subp... and do_things()

Comment: If you don't want to see "Press CTRL+C to quit" you can run it as separate thread and retrieve stdout when you need it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [retry](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/retry) package, this will help overcome your problem. Ultimately, you set *what* you are looking to try again, *what* exception you want to retry on, and you can set specific timing parameters based on how you want to retry. It's pretty well documented.

Here is an example of how I solved this in one of the projects I was working on [here](https://github.com/internap/fake-ubersmith/blob/e7f53cf0fcf2448f7b0632b454a17faed369bc2c/tests/integration/base.py#L48)

Here is the snippet of code that will help you, in case that link does not work:

```
@classmethod
def _start_app_locally(cls):
    subprocess.Popen(["fake-ubersmith"])
    retry_call(
        requests.get,
        fargs=["{}/status".format(cls.endpoint)],
        exceptions=RequestException,
        delay=1
    )
```

As you can see I just tried to hit my endpoint with a `get` using `requests` (the `fargs` are the arguments passed to `requests.get` as you can see it calls *back* the method you pass to `retry_call`), and based on the `RequestException` I was expecting, I would retry with a 1 second delay.

Finally, "fake-ubersmith" is the command that will run your server, which is ultimately your similar command of: `'python', '../../app/StubbyServer.py'`

Comment: So if I understand your approach correctly, you make a request that's not part of your test until the request is successful and therefore know that flask has started? This might work for me too

Comment: @Altoyyr Precisely. The goal for this chunk of code is just to determine that my service is up and running and I can successfully hit the endpoint. Then I can proceed with my tests to hit the endpoints I want to actually test. This in itself can also be seen as a test as well to make sure that your app successfully goes up and the endpoint can be reached.

Comment: OK thanks, I am quite sure this works for me too. I have a bit of a weird scenario, but I think I can make this work. Great answer!