# Python: How to wait until a subprocess finishes initializing

Tags: python, sockets, server, redis, subprocess

I am trying to create a Redis temporary instance for unit testing:

```
class RedisTemporaryInstance:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['redis-server', '--port', '6399'],
                                        stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'),
                                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        subprocess.call(['redis-cli', '-p', '6399', 'shutdown'])
```

But when I am using it like this:

```
import redis
with RedisTemporaryInstance() as temp:
    red = redis.Redis(port=6399)
    print(red.ping())
```

i am getting

```
ConnectionError: Error 111 connecting to localhost:6399. Connection refused.
```

However when I am adding a small sleep

```
with RedisTemporaryInstance() as temp:
    sleep(0.01)
    red = redis.Redis(port=6399)
    print(red.ping())
```

everything works fine. So apparently the server is not ready yet to accept connections without the sleep.

My question is: is there a better way to wait for the server to be ready instead of adding an arbitrary sleep duration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait for stdout on Popen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44486639/wait-for-stdout-on-popen)

Comment: Take a look at the duplicate just raised. If you use the retry package you can craft a call that will keep trying to connect to the redis server to at least check if it is "up", and once it is, you can proceed with your tests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use Popen to start the redis server. This takes its time (in your case 0.01sec), because of opening the process and the listen connection to your interface. Popen is non-blocking, so the command will set on your system, and the code goes on. This is while the `with` statement is done before redis-server is up. I think you have to use `redis-cli ping` in a blocking call (with `subprocess.call`), after starting the redis server:

```
class RedisTemporaryInstance:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['redis-server', '--port', '6399'],
                                    stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'),
                                    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        subprocess.call(['redis-cli', '-p', '6399', 'ping'])
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        subprocess.call(['redis-cli', '-p', '6399', 'shutdown'])
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wait for the server initialize as part of your **enter** method.
You can check for an open port with an helper method:

```
def check_socket(host, port):
    import socket
    from contextlib import closing
    with closing(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)) as sock:
        if sock.connect_ex((host, port)) == 0:
            return True
        else: 
            return False

class RedisTemporaryInstance:
    def __enter__(self):
        self.process = subprocess.Popen(['redis-server', '--port', '6399'],
                                        stdout=open(os.devnull, 'wb'),
                                        stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        retries = 5
        while not check_socket('127.0.0.1', 6399) and retries > 0:
            sleep(0.1)
            retries -= 1
        if retries == 0:
            print 'failure'
        return self
```

That way you'll get the Redis object only after it is initialized